# Elliptic operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

How to show that the operator
\begin{align*}
L[u]\equiv \frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}-\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}
\end{align*}
is not elliptic?

Define $L[u]\equiv A\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+B\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+C\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}+D\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}+E\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial z}+F\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial z}+G\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}+H\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}+J\frac {\partial u}{\partial z}+Ku$, where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$, $G$, $H$, $J$ may depend upon $x$, $y$, and $z$ to be elliptic if there is a linear transformation to new coordinates $(\xi, \eta, \zeta)$ such that in these coordinates,
\begin{align*}
L[u]\equiv \alpha[\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi^2}+\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial \eta^2}+\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial \zeta^2}]+\beta\frac {\partial u}{\partial \xi}+\gamma\frac {\partial u}{\partial \eta}+\delta\frac {\partial u}{\partial \zeta}+Ku
\end{align*}

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? To start, maybe you could write out what it means for an operator to be elliptic.

Comment: If I assume it's an elliptic operator, I don't know what to do next.@Carmeister

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear differential operator with constant coefficients is elliptic iff it's characteristic polynomial is non-zero for non-zero inputs.

The characteristic polynomial of your operator is $p(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$ and the equation $p(x,y,z)=0$ has plenty of non-zero solutions.